Why do researchers wear white hats when handling lunar samples?

Credit: Nature, which in turn credits Xinhua / Shutterstock
The caption says "Researchers retrieve lunar samples from the Chang’e-6 return capsule".
Why are they wearing white hats? Only reason I can think of is they have long hair and the hats are to keep hair in place, but it doesn't seem like any of the researchers have long hair.

Humans are constantly shedding hair, dead skin flakes and microbes. Note the elasticized sleeves, waist and pant cuffs. These are to intercept the constant outflow of old skin squamous cells. What OR staff refer to as "perineal fallout".

@Woody What does OR stand for?

Probably 'operating room', for medical surgeries

@Allure ... "operating room". Sorry for the unexplained abbreviation.

If anyone wants to "play cleanroom", I found this site where you can purchase the apparel: https://www.ctcleanroom.com/products/cleanroom/apparel.php?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi_G5BhDXARIsAN5SX7oV82ukrlFHyP5q1xVVg0EVztaYx9ien-clEkQ5QPTYSb7Lc2wSIKEaAiTBEALw_wcB#top

Why ... white? Most of the dirt in the world is not-white. If you want to be able to see at a glance whether or not some surface is clean, it helps if the surface is white.

@SolomonSlow Like the "white glove" test that ordinary people use to tell if a home surface is clean.

the surprise isn't what's covered, it's what's not - I'd expect masks

@Woody shouldn't they be wearing masks too then? Their breathing would also introduce tons of contamination...

These hats are likely part of a cleanroom suit. Cleanroom suits are used in cleanrooms (unsurprisingly).
Cleanrooms themselves are used when you want to avoid contaminating something with the particles and organisms from the environment. Given that they don't want to contaminate the samples they are looking at, they likely use a cleanroom and hence a cleanroom suit.
NASA uses cleanroom suits when handling lunar samples.

Hmm, I wonder why the suits don't cover the face, some hair is still exposed, and the person on the far right appears not to have to don one.

@Allure ... I suspect we are witnessing "clean room theatre" judging by the protocol failure of having an unsuited personnel within arms length of the sample. They may be rehearsing the protocol or staging a photo-op.

@Woody staging a photo-op it is

@Woody also notice the street shoes everyone is wearing rather than clean room shoe covers!

@Woody Definitely quite far from any serious clean room setup. If they're rehearsing the protocol they're rehearsing it pretty badly. A (bad) photo-op is more likely.

@jwenting ... yes, they are street shoes, but all the same style of shoe. They may be designated "clean room shoes". Booties are only used to cover shoes which have been worn outside the clean room. Booties are a slipping hazard, so designated clean room shoes are preferable and pretty standard for clean room occupations.

@Woody it's basically a uniform, designed to be reminiscent of a clean-room

@Allure It's the same as a restaurant, if the person has facial hair, then they have to cover it up. The style shown here is mainly to reduce hair and lint, which is big enough to cause persistent leaks in high vac seals. Skin flakes are small enough that they usually don't. It also is useful to prevent gross FOD, like clothing buttons, jewelry, stuff at the bottom of your pocket.
